# Is this use of volatile in TBB bug?

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition, volatile

Recently Eric Niebler had a [tweet](https://twitter.com/ericniebler/status/1378073866258411520) about volatile and thread safety and somebody replied with the link to following code from Intel TBB.

```
void Block::shareOrphaned(intptr_t binTag, unsigned index)
{
    MALLOC_ASSERT( binTag, ASSERT_TEXT );
    // unreferenced formal parameter warning
    tbb::detail::suppress_unused_warning(index);
    STAT_increment(getThreadId(), index, freeBlockPublic);
    markOrphaned();
    if ((intptr_t)nextPrivatizable==binTag) {
        // First check passed: the block is not in mailbox yet.
        // Need to set publicFreeList to non-zero, so other threads
        // will not change nextPrivatizable and it can be zeroed.
        if ( !readyToShare() ) {
            // another thread freed an object; we need to wait until it finishes.
            // There is no need for exponential backoff, as the wait here is not for a lock;
            // but need to yield, so the thread we wait has a chance to run.
            // TODO: add a pause to also be friendly to hyperthreads
            int count = 256;
            while( (intptr_t)const_cast<Block* volatile &>(nextPrivatizable)==binTag ) {
                if (--count==0) {
                    do_yield();
                    count = 256;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    MALLOC_ASSERT( publicFreeList.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) !=NULL, ASSERT_TEXT );
    // now it is safe to change our data
    previous = NULL;
    // it is caller responsibility to ensure that the list of blocks
    // formed by nextPrivatizable pointers is kept consistent if required.
    // if only called from thread shutdown code, it does not matter.
    (intptr_t&)(nextPrivatizable) = UNUSABLE;
}
```

as an example of wrong use of volatile (since it guarantees nothing wrt threading).

Is this really a  bug?

My first intuition is yes, but then again TBB is not some anon person github project, so I am curious if I am missing something.

[github link](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/blob/9e15720bc7744f85dff611d34d65e9099e077da4/src/tbbmalloc/frontend.cpp#L1530)

Comment: definitely  `nextPrivatizable` should be an atomic. Problem with multithreading code it is hard to test it and it is hard to prove that it is correct or not. I think you should file a bug report or ask TBB authors for feedback/explanation why they think this is Ok.

Comment: Note that git history starts quite recently with commits indicating that code was just copied from other source. So it may turn out this code is much older then C++11 and in fact this is a legacy code.

Comment: If all platforms on which this code is meant to run have coherent caches and guarantee atomicity of reads of that size and alignment at platform level, then it's just some crappy code, but there's no bug. `volatile` there prevents the compiler from optimizing the read. And given the structure of the loop, there isn't anything that can be reordered here, either.

Comment: @rsutyx There _is_ a bug. The C++ standard states that this has undefined behaviour. You cannot say "oh well the compiler is unlikely to do anything bad with it" or "on all CPUs that is probably ok". Undefined behaviour is undefined. No ifs. No buts.

Comment: http://isvolatileusefulwiththreads.in/C++/ (slightly glib, but had useful links on that page)